# Change Value of Parent Property in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, oop, inheritance, static

I've got a parent class with some default properties. In the child class, I want to update those properties directly, without using a method. Why? I believe it's a clean way of defining functionality in the child class.

So here's my parent class:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class BaseFormRequest extends FormRequest 
{
    protected static $NEEDS_AUTHORIZATION = false;
    protected static $FORM_RULES          = [];

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize() : bool
    {
        //dd($this->authorize);
        return self::$NEEDS_AUTHORIZATION;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() : array
    {
        return self::$FORM_RULES;
    }
}
```

In my child class, I'd like to do something similar to the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\BaseFormRequest;

class RegisterUserRequest extends BaseFormRequest
{

    protected static $NEEDS_AUTHORIZATION = true;
    protected static $FORM_RULES = [ /* specific form rules for this form */];
}
```

I don't know whether this would be the right way to do it. My question is whether I can do something similar? If I have 5 form request classes extending **BaseFormRequest** I'd just need to override **NEEDS_AUTHORIZATION** and **FORM_RULES**, which looks much cleaner than creating the same methods (`authorize()` and `rules()`) over and over in every class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it. If it's not working for you right now, it's because you are not taking advantage of [late static binding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

Basically, in your methods `rules()` and  `authorize()` you are making reference to `self`, whereas you should be making reference to `static` for this to work as you would expect.

E.g.:

```php
public function rules() : array {
   return static::$FORM_RULES;
}
```

You can see an example of this working [here](https://3v4l.org/rDkvl)

Comment: It works! Awesome :) Question: Is what I'm trying to do a good way to keep the code clean? or do you see something wrong design-wise?

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing more about your whole system. In the end it's a matter of choice and style. At first sight, I do not love it. But I guess there could be uses for it. Finding the right approach is something you'll need to do on your own by doing additional research.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Constructors for your purpose.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\BaseFormRequest;

class RegisterUserRequest extends BaseFormRequest
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        BaseFormRequest::NEEDS_AUTHORIZATION = true;
        BaseFormRequest::FORM_RULES = [ /* specific form rules for this form */];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of that. The whole point of the question is that I just wanna set the value of two properties NOT using a method, any method. Can it be done someway? or am I damned to use a method to do so?